# How to sample from DataFrame based on percentile of a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sample, percentile

Given a dataset like this:

```
import pandas as pd

rows = [{'key': 'ABC', 'freq': 100}, {'key': 'DEF', 'freq': 60}, 
{'key': 'GHI', 'freq': 50}, {'key': 'JKL', 'freq': 40}, 
{'key': 'MNO', 'freq': 13}, {'key': 'PQR', 'freq': 11}, 
{'key': 'STU', 'freq': 10}, {'key': 'VWX', 'freq': 10}, 
{'key': 'YZZ', 'freq': 3}, {'key': 'WHYQ', 'freq': 3}, 
{'key': 'HOWEE', 'freq': 2}, {'key': 'DUH', 'freq': 1}, 
{'key': 'HAHA', 'freq': 1}]

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)

df['percent'] = df['freq'] / sum(df['freq'])
```

[out]:

```
key freq    percent
0   ABC 100 0.328947
1   DEF 60  0.197368
2   GHI 50  0.164474
3   JKL 40  0.131579
4   MNO 13  0.042763
5   PQR 11  0.036184
6   STU 10  0.032895
7   VWX 10  0.032895
8   YZZ 3   0.009868
9   WHYQ    3   0.009868
10  HOWEE   2   0.006579
11  DUH 1   0.003289
12  HAHA    1   0.003289
```

The goal is to

1. select 1 example from the top 50-100 percentile of the frequency
2. select 2 examples from the 10-50 percentile and
3. select 4 example from < 10 percentile

In this case, the answer that fits are:

1. Pick 1 from `['ABC', 'DEF']`
2. Pick 2 from `['GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO', 'PQR']`
3. Pick 4 from `['VWX', 'STU', 'YZZ', 'WHYQ', 'HOWEE', 'HAHA', 'DUH']`

I've tried this:

```
import random
import pandas as pd

rows = [{'key': 'ABC', 'freq': 100}, {'key': 'DEF', 'freq': 60}, 
{'key': 'GHI', 'freq': 50}, {'key': 'JKL', 'freq': 40}, 
{'key': 'MNO', 'freq': 13}, {'key': 'PQR', 'freq': 11}, 
{'key': 'STU', 'freq': 10}, {'key': 'VWX', 'freq': 10}, 
{'key': 'YZZ', 'freq': 3}, {'key': 'WHYQ', 'freq': 3}, 
{'key': 'HOWEE', 'freq': 2}, {'key': 'DUH', 'freq': 1}, 
{'key': 'HAHA', 'freq': 1}]

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
df['percent'] = df['freq'] / sum(df['freq'])

bin_50_100 = []
bin_10_50 = []
bin_10 = []

total_percent = 1.0
for idx, row in df.sort_values(by=['freq', 'key'], ascending=False).iterrows():
    if total_percent > 0.5:
        bin_50_100.append(row['key'])
    elif 0.1 < total_percent < 0.5:
        bin_10_50.append(row['key'])
    else:
        bin_10.append(row['key'])
    total_percent -= row['percent']

    
    
print(random.sample(bin_50_100, 1))
print(random.sample(bin_10_50, 2))
print(random.sample(bin_10, 4))
```

[out]:

```
['DEF']
['MNO', 'PQR']
['HOWEE', 'WHYQ', 'HAHA', 'DUH']
```

**But is there a simpler way to solve the problem?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's try:

```
bins = [0, 0.1, 0.5, 1]
samples = [3,3,1]

df['sample'] = pd.cut(df.percent[::-1].cumsum(),  # accumulate percentage
                              bins=[0, 0.1, 0.5, 1],      # bins
                              labels=False             # num samples 
                             ).astype(int)


df.groupby('sample').apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=samples[x['sample'].iloc[0])] )
```

Output:

```
             key  freq   percent  sample
sample                                  
1      0     ABC   100  0.328947       1
2      2     GHI    50  0.164474       2
       5     PQR    11  0.036184       2
4      7     VWX    10  0.032895       4
       6     STU    10  0.032895       4
       12   HAHA     1  0.003289       4
       10  HOWEE     2  0.006579       4
```

Comment: Ah this is assuming that the no. of samples are unique. I.e. `1 2 4` but otherwise, it'll throw a `Categorical categories must be unique` error.

Comment: Thanks for the update!! Why is it `samples = np.array([3,3,1])` ?

Comment: That's for advance numpy array indexing. Passing `label=False` to cuts returns the bins numbers. e.g. `[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1]`. Then we use numpy indexing to slice the corresponding number of samples.

Comment: I'm getting different output from yours.

Comment: With the [3, 3, 1], I'm only getting 2 bins' samples, not 3 =(

Comment: @alvas ah, yes, silly me. Updated the answer. We don't need to do `np.array` for `samples`.

Comment: I think there's some syntax error at the last grouby but I think I get the idea =) Thank you!!

Comment: `df.groupby('sample').apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=samples[x['sample'].iloc[0]]))` =)

Answer (score 4):

See if this helps.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
df['percent'] = df['freq'] / sum(df['freq'])

s = list(1 - df['percent'].cumsum())
s.pop(-1)
s.insert(0,1.0)
df['cum_lag'] = s

print(df[df['cum_lag'] > 0.5]['key'])
```